# java initializing variable for stream in/out

Tags: java, objectinputstream, datainputstream

I have a problem with the below code. It is not clear how I can initialize the variables of in/out.

During the creation of this object the program hangs when in the constructor.  It hangs at the line of the `this.inObjects = new ObjectIn.........`.  I would like to create those in/out objects once only to read and write on the input/output, strings and objects by just calling them in the methods and applying read write etc etc

Where am I going wrong?  Is it possible that by not receiving data they hangs?  They shouldn't, right?

```
public class PokerClient 
{
    private PokerClientGui gui;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private DataInputStream in;
    private DataOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream inObjects;
    private ObjectOutputStream outObjects;
    private Hand hand;

    //constructor
    public PokerClient()
    {
        try
        {
            this.gui= gui;
            this.clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
            this.in = new DataInputStream(this.clientSocket.getInputStream());
            this.inObjects = new ObjectInputStream(this.clientSocket.getInputStream());
            this.output = new DataOutputStream(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            this.outObjects = new ObjectOutputStream(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always create the object output stream first and flush it.  You should never wrap the same stream two different ways. Never catch an exception and ignore it unless you like having errors and no way to determine what has gone wrong. Don't assign a field to itself, this won't do anything useful, it will just confuse people.

```
public class PokerClient {
  private final PokerClientGui gui;
  private final Socket clientSocket;
  private final ObjectOutputStream outObjects;
  private final ObjectInputStream inObjects;

  public PokerClient(PokerClientGui gui) throws IOException {
    this.gui = gui;
    clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
    outObjects = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    outObjects.flush();
    inObjects = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
  }
}
```

Comment: thx!  ( sorry for the field autoassigning ) i ll try tomorrrow this!

Answer (score 1):

Swap the two lines, i.e., use this order:

```
this.outObjects = new ObjectOutputStream(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream());
this.inObjects = new ObjectInputStream(this.clientSocket.getInputStream());
```

The constructor of OIS waits for some header, you must send first, otherwise it always blocks.

Comment: i tried to swap  but  it hangs again... instead if i comment all the lines it works... and  if even i left only the  first one : 
this.in = new DataInputStream(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()); it runs ok...... is it because i dont send or receive anything durng this part of the program ?

Comment: There's no problem with DataInputStream, only ObjectInputStream blocks since it expects some input. Use a debugger or some printing to find out where it hangs. I'm sure about what I wrote, since I ran into the problem myself and you can find it somewhere in the Javadoc.

Comment: Drop the data streams, you can use the object streams for plain data, too. `interface ObjectInput extends DataInput`. However, I don't see how it could cause problems in your example.

Comment: +0: You say "you must send first", but your example creates the sender second.  Isn't this confusing?

Comment: It may be, but otherwise I could write "swap the two lines". I'll change it.